# d3 not reacting to node hash change in other require file

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hash, requirejs

I have a javascript project using RequireJS.  I have a **d3-and-svg.js** file, and here is a preview of it:

```
var nodes = {
    "at":   {id: "at", importance: 1, type: 'exercise', displayName: 'pigeonhole principal'},
    "b":    {id: "b", importance: 8, type: "theorem", displayName: 'pigeonhole theorem'},
},
    links = []

var width = $(window).width(),
    height = $(window).height()

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes) // here is where the nodes go in
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .linkStrength(0.2)
    .gravity(0.05)
    .on('tick', updateSVGNodeAndLinkPositions)
```

I have modified my **d3** library to accept hashes, like so:

```
force.nodes = function(x) {
  if (!arguments.length) return nodes;
  // setup helper function
  function hash_to_array(hash) {
    var array = [];
    for( key in hash ){ if( hash.hasOwnProperty(key) ){
      array.push( hash[key] );
    }}
    return array;
  };
  nodes = hash_to_array(x); // this means that .nodes() takes a HASH as input and uses the values
  // nodes = x; // what it used to say
  return force;
};
```

And in my **main.js** file, I kickoff the d3 force animation, like so:

```
d3AndSVG.processNewGraph();
```

and it WORKS!  It WORKS!  But the funny thing is, if I replace `nodes` with an empty hash in my **d3-and-svg.js** file, and then populate it via my **main.js** file instead, like so:

```
d3AndSVG.nodes = {
    "at":   {id: "at", importance: 1, type: 'exercise', displayName: 'pigeonhole principal'},
    "b":    {id: "b", importance: 8, type: "theorem", displayName: 'pigeonhole theorem'},
}
d3AndSVG.processNewGraph();
```

Then it does NOT work.  Why not?  The only thing I can think of is that the values of the hash are references, and **d3-and-svg.js** can't access them when they are in the other file.  But I am not sure about this, nor can I think of a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you've shown, it cannot work. You define `nodes`:

```
var nodes = ...
```

which presumably is local to your module's factory (the function you pass to `define`). Then you use it as:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes) // here is where the nodes go in
    ...
```

This `nodes`, again local to your module's factory. Perhaps you forgot to actually export nodes, which you'd do with `exports.nodes = nodes`. **However, this alone won't do it**. See, when you do this outside your module:

```
d3AndSVG.nodes = // whatever
```

You are changing the *exported* value of `nodes` (i.e. what you set with `exports.nodes = ...`) to refer to a different object. *However*, the *local* value of `nodes`, which is what you are actually using with `force` remains unchanged. The situation is the same as in this interactive Node.js session:

```
> var a = { foo: 'a'}
> a
{ foo: 'a' }
> var b = a
> b
{ foo: 'a' }
> b = { foo: 'b' } // We assign a new object to `b`.
{ foo: 'b' }
> b
{ foo: 'b' }
> a
{ foo: 'a' }
```

The value of `a` did not change when I assigned a new object to `b`.

What you can do to have your code honor changes to `d3AndSVG.nodes` is have your code that uses `nodes` use `exports.nodes` instead:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(exports.nodes) // here is where the nodes go in
    ...
```

Comment: Let me know whether or not this is correct.  `d3AndSVG.nodes` and the local `nodes` both hold the same *reference*  to the actual object.  If the actual object was an array, then I could use `d3AndSVG.nodes.push(element)`, and it would work.  Similarly, if the actual object was a hash, then I could use `$.extend(d3AndSVG.nodes, {key: "value"})` and it would work.

Comment: But for some reason, `$.extend` is not working.  Could there be something else at play?

Comment: Well the other difference between initializing the local `nodes` with content and editing it from **main.js** is that in the latter case, d3 is adding the nodes *after* initializing the graph.  Perhaps this is the other issue.  I think this line `var node = svg.selectAll('.node').data(force.nodes(), d => d.id)` may relate to that (where SVG stuff is updated).